# How can we send a custom function as a parameter to foreach in distributedR?

Tags: r, distributed-computing, vertica, distributed-r

In a R distributed data frame I am trying subset the data using the timestamps and in the subset of data frame I want to fill the  'NA' with most frequent value of the particular column or I want to use a custom function defined to fill the 'NA's

```
foreach(i, 1:npartitions(testset_dr),
    init<-function(input = splits(testset_dr,i),uniques = uniques,output=splits(filledDF, i), index=i){
      output$hub = 'ga'
      for(i in 1:length(uniques))
      {
        lookup.subset <- subset(input,input$lookup == uniques[i])
        for(j in 1:ncol(lookup.subset)){
          output <- rbind(output,lookup.subset)
        }
      }
      update(output)
    })
```

the data set is  as below

```
ti X1 X2
t1 1  2
t1 2  2
t1 na 1
t1 1  na
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 na 1
```

subset based on t1

```
t1 1  2
t1 2  2
t1 na 1
t1 1  na
```

subset based on t2

```
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 na 1
```

from the two subset trying to substitute NAs with frequently occurred value of that column

and the expected output is

```
ti X1 X2
t1 1  2
t1 2  2
t1 1  1
t1 1  2
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
t2 1  1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and which problems did you experience? Could you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: @Cleb I have added the sample code and data frame